# Finding the minimum distance for each row using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matrix

I am trying to match DNA spiral of different bacterias with  their ancestors and I have around 1 million observations. I want to identify the closest ancestor for each bacteria, i.e. I want to compare them with same or older generation ( equal or smaller generation numbers) so my data frame looks like this (for simplicity let's assume DNA vector consist of one number):

```
bacteria_id  generation DNA_vector 
213           230        23
254           230        18
256           229        39
289           229        16
310           228        24
324           228        45
```

I tried to create a matrix and choose the smallest value from that matrix for each bacteria but as it will consist of lot of rows and columns, I get `memory error` before matrix is created. 
Let's assume that it is not bacteria but car and I compare each car with its own generation (e.g. cars launched in 2010) and with the older ones. And also let's change DNA_vector to number of features. And I will assume it is more similar to other car if the difference between number of features is smaller. 
So I want to create two additional columns. First one will tell the minimum difference (e.g. for the first one it will be 1, and the most similar car will be model 310)

Expected output is:

```
bacteria_id  generation DNA_vector most_similar_bacteria  distance
213           230        23             310               1 (i.e. 24 -23)
254           230        18             289               2
256           229        39             324               6                
289           229        16             228               8  
310           228        24             324               19
324           228        45              NA               NA
```

Do you have any recommendations?

Comment: Could you please remove all reference to genetics and ask the question in a broad topic? It is hard to understand the question when you don't know what comparison you want to use

Comment: oh ok , I will simplify it

Comment: Is it more clear now ?

Comment: The straight forward way to do this is to loop over your DF twice. For each row look at all rows to compare. Then write into a new DF for each outer loop. This would be more simple with SQL like syntax and some window functions. Write up a toy example if you have trouble and somebody will fix it.

Comment: Can you add expected output, it is really confusing as to what you want accomplished.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running into memory errors because of a large dataset, you could try using dask. It is a 'parallel' computing library extremely similar to pandas that allows you to process larger datasets by using your hard drive instead of RAM.

https://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/

May not be something exactly as what you're looking for, but I have had good luck using it with large datasets as you describe.